# Removing an element from the CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove a small button/element that is under my preloader. I am trying to figure out exactly what kind of css file controls that but I am unable to remove that element under the preloader. I thought adding `overflow:hidden` to the `svg` would do the trick but it still did not.

This is the code of the preloader:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&family=Oswald:wght@500&family=Pacifico&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,900;1,500&display=swap');



.svg-file path {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: rgb(1, 36, 133);
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    stroke-dasharray: 550;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    animation: animate-zlogo 2s linear infinite;
}

svg {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    transform: scale(2);
}

.svg-file h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto", cursive;
    transform: translate(0, 50px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #044d77;
}

.svg-file span {
    animation: dots 2.5s steps(6, end) infinite;
    font-size: 5em;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0, 65px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    background-color: rgb(5, 46, 80);
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}

@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -50;
    }

    20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    40% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #05f7f9;    
        }

    80% {
        stroke-width: 0;
       fill: #05f7f9;
    }

    100% {
        /* stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
        stroke-width: 3;
        fill: transparent;
    }
}
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.z-logo svg {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.z-logo::before {
  content: "";
    top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
  <div class="svg-file z-logo">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 133 133" width="133" height="133">
      <g id="H">
        <path d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z" fill="#47AF9A" />
      </g>
    </svg>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the element I want to remove under my preloader:

[image: element to be removed]

Comment: That's the empty `<span></span>` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `<span></span>` from your HTML code.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@500;700&family=Montserrat:wght@400;600&family=Oswald:wght@500&family=Pacifico&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,900;1,500&display=swap');



.svg-file path {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: rgb(1, 36, 133);
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    stroke-dasharray: 550;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.svg-file.z-logo path {
    animation: animate-zlogo 2s linear infinite;
}

svg {
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
    transform: scale(2);
}

.svg-file h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto", cursive;
    transform: translate(0, 50px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #044d77;
}

.svg-file span {
    animation: dots 2.5s steps(6, end) infinite;
    font-size: 5em;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0, 65px) skewX(-210deg) rotate(-6deg);
    background-color: rgb(5, 46, 80);
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}

@keyframes fadein-fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes animate-zlogo {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: -50;
    }

    20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 550;
        fill: transparent;
    }

    40% {
        fill: transparent;
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
    }

    60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 1100;
        fill: #05f7f9;    
        }

    80% {
        stroke-width: 0;
       fill: #05f7f9;
    }

    100% {
        /* stroke-dashoffset: 0; */
        stroke-width: 3;
        fill: transparent;
    }
}
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.z-logo svg {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.z-logo::before {
  content: "";
    top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader">
  <div class="svg-file z-logo">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 133 133" width="133" height="133">
      <g id="H">
        <path d="M45.33 78.22L87.67 78.22L87.67 133L121.05 133L121.05 0L87.67 0L87.67 49.33L45.33 49.33L45.33 0L11.95 0L11.95 133L45.33 133L45.33 78.22Z" fill="#47AF9A" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```